node.js : npm ERR! network getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
While attempting to install any package using NPM, I am seeing an error message like npmERR! network getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND. Although I am aware that there are several posts discussing this similar problem, I was unable to locate any that would be helpful.
Is there a way for me to verify that the URL I'm using to set my proxy is correct? Are there any actions I should take to address this problem?

The error getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND appears if the package is published, but not in a located server or when you are not connected to internet (what's all i know of this error), disable the VPN may can solve the problem, if you has one, or see your proxy connection
you can delete your proxy with npm delete proxy or check if you are setting your proxy like this:
npm config set proxy http://example.com:port

also you can use yarn to install these packages, not every package can be installed with just npm
